# Conjugate[a/b + c/d]

Tags: complex, algebraic-manipulation

Trying to obtain the result of Conjugate[a/b+c/d] only gives the same result. As such, I use Refine as:

```
Refine[
  Conjugate[a/b + c/d], a ∈ Complexes && b ∈ Reals && c ∈ Reals && d ∈ Complexes]
```

with the output

> `Conjugate[a/b + c/d]`

Funny thing is that if I try

```
Refine[Conjugate[a/b + c/d],a ∈ Reals && b ∈ Reals && c ∈ Reals && d ∈ Reals]
```

I get

> `a/b + c/d`

or, if I try

```
Refine[Conjugate[a/b + c], a ∈ Complexes && b ∈ Reals && c ∈ Reals]
```

I get

> `c + Conjugate[a]/b`

As soon as I have two fractions inside `Conjugate`], with any of the elements as Complex, I do not get the conjugate of each element, which is my obvious goal. Any reason why this happens?

I manage to get the desired result in this case for example:

```
In[252]:= Distribute@
 Conjugate[fc (2 E^((2 I fc \[Pi] (R1 + R2))/\[ConstantC]) mu1 c)]

Out[252]= 2 E^(-((2 I \[Pi] Conjugate[fc (R1 + R2)])/
  Conjugate[\[ConstantC]])) Conjugate[c fc mu1]

In[253]:= FullSimplify[%]

Out[253]= 2 E^(-((2 I fc \[Pi] (R1 + R2))/\[ConstantC])) fc Conjugate[
  c] Conjugate[mu1]

In[254]:= TraditionalForm[%]

Out[254]//TraditionalForm= 2 fc c^\[Conjugate] mu1^\[Conjugate] E^(-((2 I \[Pi] fc (R1+R2))/\[ConstantC]))
```

However as soon as I try to do it for

> Distribute@
>    Conjugate[
>     fc (2 E^((2 I fc [Pi] (R1 + R2))/[ConstantC]) mu1 c + 
>        E^((4 I fc [Pi] R1)/[ConstantC]) mu2 d)]

the same series of commands produces only

```
fc (2 c E^((2 I fc \[Pi] (R1+R2))/\[ConstantC]) mu1+d E^((4 I fc \[Pi] R1)/\[ConstantC]) mu2)^\[Conjugate]
```

not what I would expect the result to be

```
2 fc c^\[Conjugate] mu1^\[Conjugate] E^(-((2 I \[Pi] fc (R1+R2))/\[ConstantC])) + fc d^\[Conjugate] mu2^\[Conjugate] E^(-((4 I \[Pi] fc R1)/\[ConstantC]))
```

Comment: Do avoid using `C` and `D` for this, as they are reserved symbols.

Comment: Yes, it was just an example. I actually have more complicated terms than A, B, C or D. Thanks for the quick input!

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You should edit the question to fix the caps, it is distracting from the issue.  I suspect the problem is simply that the result you "expect" is regarded as more complicated than the result you get.

Comment: `Conjugate[a/b + c/d]`  returns `Conjugate[a/b + c/d]`. What else did you expect? Your error is in using capital C and D. They are reserved, and Mma could not understand you.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I have now edited my question to avoid confusion with the reserved symbols.

Comment: This was just a dummy example using a,b,c and d. I actually have some complicated formulations for these. What I would expect to obtain when using `Refine[Conjugate[a/b+c/d],a \[Element] Complexes && b \[Element] 
Reals && c \[Element] Reals && d \[Element] Complexes]` is `Conjugate[a]/b + c/Conjugate[d]`, however the output is `Conjugate[a/b+c/d]`.

Comment: Try `Distribute@Conjugate[a/b + c/d]`.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you might want `Conjugate[Together[a/b + c/d]]`

Comment: @swish Thanks! I tried using your solution, however I still don't get the the expected result. For example `Distribute@
 Conjugate[
  fc (2 E^((2 I fc \[Pi] (R1 + R2))/\[ConstantC]) mu1 c[1] + 
     E^((4 I fc \[Pi] R1)/\[ConstantC]) mu2 d[1])]` produces `Conjugate[
 fc (2 E^((2 I fc \[Pi] (R1 + R2))/\[ConstantC]) mu1 c[1] + 
    E^((4 I fc \[Pi] R1)/\[ConstantC]) mu2 d[1])]`, when I specify for each variable if it is real or complex.

Comment: Try 'FunctionExpand'.

Answer (score 1):

I find that getting the answer I want with this type of expression requires the use of a range of techniques.  In this case,  I would use

```
ComplexExpand[Conjugate[a/b + c/d], {a, d},  TargetFunctions -> Conjugate]
```

giving

```
Conjugate[a]/b + c/Conjugate[d]
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to distribute every product over sums in your expression in order for `Conjugate` to propagate properly:

```
distributeProducts[expr_] := 
 Replace[expr, t : Times[___] :> Distribute[t], {0, \[Infinity]}]

distributeProducts@
 Conjugate[
  fc (2 c E^((2 I fc \[Pi] (R1 + R2))/\[ConstantC]) mu1 + 
     d E^((4 I fc \[Pi] R1)/\[ConstantC]) mu2)]
```